# How to allow terminal executed apps to draw on phone display that runs on ubuntu touch

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, xserver, nexus-4, x11-forwarding

Using apt-get i've found serval well-known and handy applications, but unofortunately i cannot execute them neither via phone terminal application or trough ssh. I found also that there is no DISPLAY variable specified, and even when i set it as localhost:0 it will just print out that it cannot use that screen (or some other fatal err). So where is the problem? Aren't apt-get be supposed to fetch only reliable/compatible with ubuntu touch reposiories?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question(s) correctly. Please give us one example application you installed (locally or remotely)  and what error it gives you. Please [update your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/361845/edit) don't use the comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know from [Touch FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Which_applications_do_run_on_Ubuntu_Touch.3F)

> Ubuntu Touch is primarily designed to support web apps, and native apps programmed in qml and javascript or C++. As it is a real linux, of course all non graphical applications run equally as on any other linux system. You can ssh to Ubuntu Touch and run any console based application.
>   **X11 is not supported (so far) so all GUI standard applications will not run.**